# "Aimer à+infinitif" dans "Que j'aime à faire apprendre un nombre utile aux sages"

Tags: prépositions, verbes, infinitif, à

Voici une règle mnémonique qui donne les 11 premiers chiffres du nombre pi

> Que j'aime à faire apprendre un nombre utile aux sages : 3,1415926535...

Je ne comprends pas du point de vue de la grammaire la présence de la préposition à (aimer à faire...).

http://mateo.over-blog.org/article-un-petit-poeme-pour-retenir-le-nombre-pi-43330552.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il s'agit simplement d'une construction alternative qui n'ajoute rien au sens la plupart du temps mais que l'on trouve encore. Selon la [BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2165) c'est une construction assez rare de registre soutenu Cependant, elle n'est pas utilisé avec n'importe quel verbe ; on la trouve souvent avec les verbes « penser » et « croire » mais  d'autres conviennent aussi ([TLFi B. 2. a)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aimer)).

- <s>Ils aiment à manger dehors dans le soleil.</s> • <s>Elles aiment à courir.</s> • <s>Ils aiment à parler longtemps.</s>
- Ils aiment manger dehors dans le soleil. •  Elles aiment courir. • Ils aiment parler longtemps.

Lorsqu'utilisée avec « penser » et « croire » les locutions verbales qui résultent prennent un sens particulier selon la BDL.

- vouloir penser, vouloir croire

Le TLFi mentionne un autre cas où « aimer » prend une valeur d'auxiliaire (semi auxiliaire).

> [L'exemple suivant] montre le verbe aimer affaibli en auxil. expr. de la répét. (aime à imaginer = « imagine souvent »).

- En aucune période de l'histoire contemporaine (...) ne s'est vérifiée l'opposition simpliste entre gouvernement et commerce, ni à plus forte raison celle que la polémique aime à imaginer entre la stérilité économique de l'État et la fécondité exclusive de l'entreprise privée.

*quelques exemples tirés du dictionnaire (TLFi)* (caractères gras dus à user **LPH**)

- Quittant sa forme, hélas! Non son âme première,
  Le beau narcisse en fleur, aux rives des ruisseaux
  **Aime** encore **à se voir** dans le cristal des eaux.
- **J'aimais à lire** la Vie des Saints, ces beaux poèmes, ces dangereux romans, où l'humanité paraît si grande et si forte qu'on ne peut plus ensuite se baisser et regarder à terre les hommes tels qu'ils sont.
- Encore une bonne quinzaine pourtant, et j'espère avoir fini mon chapitre! Ce qui me donnera du revif, **j'aime à le croire**! Et au bout de trois ou quatre mois, quand le dernier chapitre sera fait, j'en aurai encore (avec le second volume) pour six ou huit mois!!!
- Le commerce des âmes est la plus grande et la seule réalité. Voilà pourquoi **j'aime à penser à** ces bons prêtres qui furent mes premiers maîtres, à ces excellents marins, qui ne vécurent que du devoir; à la petite Noémi, qui mourut parce qu'elle était trop belle; à mon grand-père, qui ne voulut pas acheter de biens nationaux; au bonhomme Système, qui fut heureux puisqu'il eut son heure d'illusion.
- ... un bon éditeur devrait **aimer** autant (plus peut-être) **à payer qu'à gagner**.
- J'écris ceci dans la vieille bibliothèque où **j'aime à penser qu**'Edgar Poe est venu lire et rêver quelquefois.

Voici des exemples récents qui montrent que c'est une tournure qui est toujours utilisée dans la langue écrite ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aimer_%C3%A0)).

- Et c'était ainsi qu'elle prenait plaisir à lire de nouveaux livres. Et elle aimait beaucoup à lire les livres en langue anglaise, tout comme elle aimait à lire ceux en langue française. — (Maryam B., Une fille, des mots, des idées..., Books on Demand France, 2010, page 33)
- Wagner n'échappe pas à la règle: il aimait à séduire, se rassurant ainsi sur son désir de plaire, rançon d'une frustration de tendresse à la recherche de l'amante-mère qu'incarnera sa seconde femme, Cosima Liszt. — (Sylvie Oussenko & ‎François Poncet, Wagner: vie et œuvre, Éditions Eyrolles, 2013, page 22)

Dans la langue parlée, les tournures où « aimer » prend la valeur de semi auxiliaire sont, à mon avis, toujours utilisables.