# Why is there an « à » and a « les » instead of « de »?

Tags: grammaire

In Barbara Pravi's song « L'homme and L'oiseau » she does two things which I thought were grammatically incorrect. The lyrics first go « J'aime à t'imaginer danser/Au loin dans ce ciel sans limite », why is there an  « à »? Because to what I know, it's « aimer faire quelque chose » like « J'aime jouer au rugby ».

Next, the lyrics go « Oh mon amour, mon amour, je sais\Que tu repartiras bientôt\On n'enferme pas les oiseaux ». Why is it « les oiseaux » instead of « de oiseaux » because from what I've been taught, *le la* and *les* become *de* after a negative like « Je n'ai jamais eu de chats chez moi »

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first expression is literary (***aimer à***) and has already be asked and replied at least twice here (by the same OP and replier).

See: [aimer/aimer à/aimer de](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31336) and ["Aimer à+infinitif" dans "Que j'aime à faire apprendre un nombre utile aux sages"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39675)

About ***on n'enferme pas les oiseaux***, the rule is for an undefinite article (***un*** or ***des***) to become ***de*** in negative sentences so that would be *on n'enferme pas d'oiseau(x)*. However, the sentence in Pravi's song is the negation of *on enferme **les** oiseaux* so the birds are defined (either a group of birds but here, birds in general). The article stays unchanged in that case.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Aimer à**, suivi d’un infinitif, signifie Prendre plaisir à quelque chose. Aimer à jouer, à chasser, à se promener. Aimer à lire, à travailler. J’aime à voir comme vous vous conduisez avec lui. Il aime à être flatté, caressé. On dit de même Cet animal aime à courir. Cet arbuste aime à être arrosé, etc.
   [Dictionnaire de l'académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8A0778)

*Aimer à* followed by an infinitive means: take pleasure in, that is to say, love or like

And *imaginer* can take a direct object as in: Je t'imagine.

[Larousse_imaginer_transitive verb](https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/francais/imaginer/5385)

So, **j'aime à t'imaginer** translates to: I love imagining you

2. On n'enferme pas les oiseaux.

The translation is: We don't cage birds.

**Generally speaking, in making general statements**, **French uses a determiner and English does not.**

- J'aime les chiens et les chats.
- I love dogs and cats.
- Elle déteste le poisson. [as in as a food]
- She hates fish.

Answer (score 1):

Second question

The use of "les" in this sentence is the so called use for generic reference instead of the more usual use for specific reference; as in English, the distinctions of number are neutralized ; the article refers to all birds, any type of bird.

> A bird always has wings but is not  necessarily an animal that can fly. (*"Un oiseau a toujours des ailes mais ce n'est pas nécessairement  un animal qui peut voler.*", *generic reference through the use of the indefinite article, which usual  function of coding indefinite reference is replaced by that of coding generic reference*)
> Birds always have wings but are not  necessarily  animals that can fly. (*"Les oiseaux ont toujours des ailes mais ce ne sont pas des animaux qui peuvent nécessairement voler.*",  *generic reference through the use of the zero article, which is the equivalent of "les" in French*)

- On n'enferme pas d'oiseaux. (*We are not keeping any bird in a cage.*)
- On n'enferme pas les oiseaux. (*"It is not our practice to keep birds in cages.*" or according to the context, as a more general  principle in dealing with birds, as in the song, "*Birds are not kept in cages.*")